# Magento 2.3.4 xampp Admin Panel Problem

Tags: admin, admin-panel

I've installed Magento 2.3.4 on xampp 7.2.28-0.
The admin-panel didn't load so i started researching and did the following:
go to:
/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php

change:

```
$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
```

to:

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

After this I could log in but the Admin-Panel didn't load and the logos didn't show.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You going to the **etc/di.xml** file

And search the

`Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink`

And change this

`Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

And run this :-

1.Remove pub/static

2.Remove var/cache

3.Remove var/composer_home

4.Remove var/generation

5.Remove var/page_cache

6.Remove var/view_preprocessed

7.run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did everything. It didn't work. Then I tried php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f . So now I see only text and when I click on it, I land on the same page.

Comment: Please add you new screen shot

Comment: Check your console error